# Use Django admin change_list in an app

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to have the admin change_list in my app, like a generic filtered list view.  For example, I have an app "cars" and I would like a url http://www.example.com/cars/mycars/ that has a list of all the cars (that can be filtered and sorted by the column headers).

I am able to create a custom admin site and customize the admin change_list, but it ends up on a link like http://www.example.com/my_admin/cars

Is there a simple way use the nice change_list view and template of the admin site to create a generic sortable, filterable list in an app without having another link to the admin?

If not, any recommendations on how to go about this?

Thanks!
T

Comment: Not entirely sure how did your implementation, but you should've started reading [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects).

Comment: That's exactly how I've done my custom admin site, which I have on the link my_admin/cars.  What I want is to take the view and template for that style table and use it with an queryset that is not an admin_site object.  I have gotten the my_site admin page to appear on example.com/cars by changing the urls.py to attach the my_admin object to the root url, but this is limited in that you have to override a lot of the admin_site context in order to have lots of other things on the page.  It would be more preferable to have this table as a generic view/template that I could embed in my app.